# GitHub Search API only return 30 results

Tags: github-api

https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=stress+test+label:bug+language:python+state:closed

the above query is suppose to return 76 results, and when I try to run it, it only returns 30. I guess GitHub return results in portions when it is over 30. Any idea how I can get the rest of the results?

Comment: Also note that the GitHub limits any search query to 1000 results (rounded up to next multiple of page size), as mentioned [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/).

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You need to use `page` parameter, e.g. for next 30 page = 2

```
https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=stress+test+label:bug+language:python+state:closed&page=2
```

You can also use `per_page` parameter to change the default size of 30. It supports max size of 100. Like this:

```
https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=stress+test+label:bug+language:python+state:closed&per_page=100
```

More detail can be found [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination)

Comment: The above link, what if i want to search for language c++? I tried, how do I distinguish the "+"in the query?

Comment: You can replace + with %20.

Comment: The `Link` header includes a link to the next page of results. The [official GitHub API documentation states](https://developer.github.com/v3/#link-header) that, "It is important to follow these `Link` header values instead of constructing your own URLs."

Answer (score 7):

**The Problem**: Github api response doesn't contain all the relevant data.

**Solution**: The api from server is limiting the amount of items the user gets and splitting it into pages (pagination). You should explicitly Specify in your request how many items you'd like to receive from server pagination engine ,using formula for Github pagination api

```
?page=1&per_page=<numberOfItemsYouSpecify>"
```

**For example:** I'd like to get all my collaborators info in my private repo. I'm performing curl request to Github contains: username, authentication token , Organization and repository name and api call with pagination magic.

```
curl -u johnDoe:abc123$%^ https://api.github.com/repos/MyOrganizationName/MyAwesomeRepo/collaborators?page=1&per_page=1000"
```

**Explanation**:

**What is Pagination:** Pagination is the process of splitting the contents or a section of a website into discrete pages. Users tend to get lost when there's bunch of data and with pagination splitting they can concentrate on a particular amount of content. Hierarchy and paginated structure improve the readability score of the content. Loading pages is due to the less content on each item and each page has a separate URL which is easy to refer.

***In this use case Github api splits the result into 30 items per resonse, depends on the request***

Github reference:

> Different API calls respond with different defaults. For example, a
> call to List public repositories provides paginated items in sets of
> 30, whereas a call to the GitHub Search API provides items in sets of
> 100