# Downloading all Issues from a Github Repository Without Pull Requests

Tags: json, curl, github

I'm trying to get all the issues (both open and closed sans pull requests) into a .json file from the [Jabref](https://github.com/JabRef/jabref) repository. So far from [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30656761/github-search-api-only-return-30-results) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33374778/how-can-i-get-all-the-github-issues-using-github-api?noredirect=1&lq=1), I know that I need to set the status to all and modify the pagination. This is what I have so far:

```
curl -o issuesAll.json https://api.github.com/repos/JabRef/jabref/issues?per_page=100&state=all
```

But all that does is give me 100 open issues with pull requests. I tried looking at the Github API v3 documentation, but I just got confused. Is there a way to get all the issues into one file with only one command? Pagination seems to imply that I need to do one call for each page of results (since max number per page is 100)?

Answer (score 1):

You could try instead a [GraphQL query](https://developer.github.com/v4/), similar [to this one](https://developer.github.com/v4/guides/forming-calls/#example-query)

```
query {
  repository(owner:"octocat", name:"Hello-World") {
    issues(last:20, states:CLOSED) {
      edges {
        node {
          title
          url
          labels(first:5) {
            edges {
              node {
                name
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Instead of last, you can use "`before`" (the [`last` field is limited to 100 anyway](https://developer.github.com/v4/object/issueconnection/#fields))

You can [use the explorer for testing](https://developer.github.com/v4/guides/using-the-explorer/).

Comment: Thank you, but I can't seem to figure out a few things that I want to modify from this example.

Comment: I want to add OPEN to states, but I can't figure out how to have both open and closed states. I also want to iterate through all the issues, and I think I should be able to use the cursor mentioned in the documentation, but I don't see how to check this cursor to see if I am at the end of the issues, or even how to access the cursor (in a for loop?).

Comment: Yeah, I looked at a bunch of tutorials, but I am still confused about how to do this. I guess I will just manually curl 100 issues at a time.