# List of repos with Github API

Tags: github, github-api

I am trying to find the list of top `1000` `Java` repos sorted by `most stars` using GitHub API.

Code:

```
import requests
import json
r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=language:java&sort=stars&order=desc')
```

OP:

```
list_of_repos = r.json()["items"]
```

This list has only information about `30` repos, is there anyway to get the top `N` where I can pass it as the parameter?

Comment: See answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30656761/github-search-api-only-return-30-results for how to use `per_page` and `page` parameters in your query