# Get a list of all commits I have pushed in all available repositories

Tags: git, github, repository, commit

I am looking for a way to see all commits I have pushed in all repositories I am in.

Right now I only have found the commits I have pushed for a specific repository. Unfortunately this is not what I am looking for.

There is a way to view your commit history but at this history, I only see the repositories I have committed to. It does not show the commit name to me.

Answer (score 0):

The closest would be, for GitHub only, to do a search similar [as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70718093/6309), which does list all commits, sorted by date (most recent first) on all (public) repositories for a given author name.

Example for me:

https://github.com/search?o=desc&s=committer-date&type=Commits&q=author%3AVonC

Comment: That's exactly what I am looking for! Thank you very much! Do you maybe know if there is a way to get more results per page? Right now I only get 10 results per page.

Comment: @Vlame ONly api.github.com would support a per_page attribute, I believe (as [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30656830/6309)).